# How do I reset the caps lock key after remapping it to ctrl while caps lock was enabled?

Tags: xkb

I used the following command to remap my caps lock key:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -option ctrl:nocaps
```

How do I reset my keyboard to the default settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear options, use:

```bsh
setxkbmap -layout us -option ''
```

Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> down to invert caps if typing the command.

You likely have to double-tap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> afterwards to reset the lock.